# Select with where clause in MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, select, visual-studio-2013, where-clause

Is it possible to select data from a table with a specific ID? I know it works for *update* but what is the code for the *select*?

Im using c# in visual studios, my goal is to **display the details in readOnly textboxes**.

```
 string corp = 
   @"select corporateName, 
            corporateAddress, 
            corporateContact 
       from corporatemembership 
      where corporateID = CorpID.Text";
```

Comment: Please try [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/default.asp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should do it

```
string Command = 
  @"select corporateName, 
           corporateAddress, 
           corporateContact 
      from corporatemembership 
     where corporateID = @CorpID;";

using (MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    using (MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(Command, myConnection))
    {
        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@CorpID", CorpID.Text));
        DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
        myDataAdapter.Fill(dtResult);
        corporateName.Text = dtResult.Rows[0]["corporateName"];
        corporateAddress.Text = dtResult.Rows[0]["corporateAddress"];
        corporateContact.Text = dtResult.Rows[0]["corporateContact"];
    }
}
```

probably you should add some error handling and handle the case that CorpID doesn't exist

**UPDATE** another approach

```
string Command =
        @"select corporateName, 
                 corporateAddress, 
                 corporateContact 
            from corporatemembership 
            where corporateID = @CorpID;";
using (MySqlConnection mConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    mConnection.Open();
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Command, mConnection))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@CorpID", CorpID.Text));
        using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                corporateName.Text = (string)reader["corporateName"];
                corporateAddress.Text = (string)reader["corporateAddress"];
                corporateContact.Text = (string)reader["corporateContact"];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, 
your sql string is OK, except last part, you will edit last part

string corp = "select corporateName, corporateAddress, corporateContact from corporatemembership where corporateID = " + "'" + CorpID.Text + "'";